# Cursor to Int Conversion

Tags: android, cursor

I am having some trouble converting the results of a query into an integer. I am returning the results of the query into a cursor and trying to use this value again in another statement. I know the value being returned is an int but I cant seem to extract the value into an integer variable. I have also tried returning the statement into an int but that doesnt work either.

**Query**

```
public Cursor getCode(String name) throws SQLException
{
    return db.rawQuery("select recipe_code from recipes where recipe_name = " + "'"+name+"'" ,null);
}
```

**Int conversion NOW WORKING**

```
    Cursor code = adapter.getCode(string);
    code.moveToFirst();
    int test = code.getInt(0);
```

Comment: what is the value of code when you debug it?

Comment: Lots of different caracters and when I did a toString() it says `android.database.sql.SQLiteCursor@cf5778c`

Comment: try if `int i = code.getInt(0);` works..

Comment: Tried that and got this `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`

Comment: First of all, you must move the cursor on the first row. Otherwise, it's positioned at **-1**

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I got it sorted

Comment: Hey there,can you tell me what is adapter here? in  Cursor code = adapter.getCode(string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
int test = code.getInt();
```

with

```
int test = code.getInt(0);
```

You are not passing the column index as argument to `getInt()` and hence the code not working. You should specify which column to be choosen.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int))

> **public abstract int getInt (int columnIndex)**
>
> Returns the value of the requested column as an int.
>
> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column
>   value is null, the column type is not an integral type, or the integer
>   value is outside the range [Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE] is
>   implementation-defined.
>
> **Parameters** columnIndex    the zero-based index of the target column.
>
> **Returns** the value of that column as an int.